# Push/pop stack class program in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I've written and modified an example code from a C++ book about pushing/popping numbers off a stack class. This is a basic question just for my understanding.. Here is the code.

```
//stakarray.cpp
//a stack as a class
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
  private:
    enum { MAX = 10 };
    //int MAX=10;
    int st[MAX];
    int top;
  public:
    Stack()
    { top=0; }
    void push(int var)
    { st[++top]=var; } //increments stack, input var
    int pop()
    { return st[top--]; } //returns var, decrements stack
    void show(int var)
    { cout << st[var]<< endl; }
};
int main()
{
  //some stack operations
  int i;
  Stack s1;
  s1.push(11);
  s1.push(22);
  cout<<"1: "<<s1.pop()<<endl; //22
  cout<<"2: "<<s1.pop()<<endl; //11
  s1.push(33);
  s1.push(44);
  s1.push(55);
  s1.push(66);
  for (i=0; i<= 10 ; i++)
  {
   cout<< "s1[" << i << "]= ";
   s1.show(i); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program gives

```
1: 22
2: 11
s1[0]= 2
s1[1]= 33
s1[2]= 44
s1[3]= 55
s1[4]= 66
s1[5]= 0
s1[6]= 0
s1[7]= 0
s1[8]= 4196896
s1[9]= 0
s1[10]= 4
```

Why is s1[0]=2, s1[8]=4196896, s1[10]=4? Is there also any way to access MAX from private or do i have to define it somewhere else in the class (not using as global variable or part of main())?

Comment: Sounds like you should use your debugger to step through the code so you can see what happens at each line.

Answer (score 2):

Element 0 is never used, because in push you use pre-increment (++top) instead of post-increment (top++).

Your stack has at most 4 elements in it at a time, therefore all elements following index 4 have undefined content (i.e., random garbage in s1[5]...s1[10]).

Answer (score 1):

In your code you were incrementing top with a pre-increment `++top` before setting the value. Therefore, top would go to 1 and then you would set `s1[1]=33`. If you switch to post-increment `top++`, your counter variable `top` will increment after setting `s[0]=33`.

```
//stakarray.cpp
//a stack as a class
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
  private:
    enum { MAX = 10 };
    //int MAX=10;
    int st[MAX];
    int top;
  public:
    Stack()
    { top=0; }
    void push(int var)
    { st[top++]=var; } //increments stack, input var
    int pop()
    { return st[top--]; } //returns var, decrements stack
    void show(int var)
    { cout << st[var]<< endl; }
};
int main()
{
  //some stack operations
  int i;
  Stack s1;
  s1.push(11);
  s1.push(22);
  cout<<"1: "<<s1.pop()<<endl; //22
  cout<<"2: "<<s1.pop()<<endl; //11
  s1.push(33);
  s1.push(44);
  s1.push(55);
  s1.push(66);
  for (i=0; i<= 10 ; i++)
  {
   cout<< "s1[" << i << "]= ";
   s1.show(i); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```